# Play 2.5 dokku failure to deploy

Tags: playframework-2.5, dokku

I'm trying to deploy my play application with a dokku instance set up on digital ocean with 2gb ram.  I'm getting the error

```
remote: App container failed to start!!
=====> edb-fend web container output:
       Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
       setuidgid: fatal: unable to run target/universal/stage/bin/edb-fend: file does not exist
=====> end edb-fend web container output
```

I've tried googling but have found nothing.

Update

I have discovered that the scala build pack is out of date and updated it but I still receive the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact same error in heroku.  the problem is that the name of the app in my build.sbt file was

```
name := "edb"
```

but the project and repo are named edb-fend.  That alone isn't the reason, but my Procfile was looking for

```
web: target/universal/stage/bin/edb-fend
```

but activator was building edb.

I changed the build.sbt to `name := "edb-fend"` and it works now.